# PHP validate multiple email addresses using explode

Tags: php, email

I have this PHP Function to send emails to addresses in a MySQL Database:

```
require_once "/usr/local/lib/php/Mail.php";

                $from = $email_from;
                $to = $email_to;
                $subject = $email_subject;
                $body = $email_body;

                $host = "mail.domain.co.uk";
                $username = "sending@domain.co.uk";
                $password = "*********";

                $headers = array ('From' => $from,
                  'To' => $to,
                  'Cc' => $cc,
                  'Subject' => $subject,
                  'Content-type' => 'text/html');
                $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
                  array ('host' => $host,
                 'auth' => true,
                 'username' => $username,
                 'password' => $password));

                 $rec = $to.', '.$cc;

                $mail = $smtp->send($rec, $headers, $body);
```

each email address is separated by a comma like:

```
mail@domain.com,mail2@domain2.co.uk
```

I have tried using:

```
if(filter_var($email_to, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

but this only works for one email address, how can I validate multiple separated by a comma?

How can I validate the comma separated values in the `$to` and `$cc`?

Comment: I think you already said the keyword, explode, use explode function then do array walk or iterate on email and collect them in new array and later implode to get your string back from valid email only.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425124/php-validate-email-addresses-separated-by-a-comma

Answer (score 4):

You need to loop through each of the emails and validate them individually.

Like so:

```
<?php
$emails = 'mail@domain.com,mail2@domain2.co.uk';

$explode = explode(',',$emails); // Explodes the emails by the comma
$valid = true;

// Loop through each email and validate it
foreach($explode as $email) {
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $valid = false;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) with a callback, like so:

```
$validEmails = array_filter($emails, function($val) {
    return (bool) filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); 
});
```

And to get the valid emails as a comma separated string, you can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$validEmailString = implode(',',$validEmails);
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/55051)

Comment: Why not use array_filter?

Comment: @ymakux: I was probably not aware of array_filter() back then. Or might have had too much coffee or was half-asleep. Updated the answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
$valid = true;

foreach(explode(",", $email_to) as $email){
   if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
       { 
         $valid = false;
       }
}
```

all together with your code

```
require_once "/usr/local/lib/php/Mail.php";

                $from = $email_from;
                $to = $email_to;
                $subject = $email_subject;
                $body = $email_body;


    $valid = true;

    foreach(explode(",", $to) as $email){
       if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
           { 
             $valid = false;
           }
    }


if(!$valid) {

echo "Bad address"; exit; 

}

                $host = "mail.domain.co.uk";
                $username = "sending@domain.co.uk";
                $password = "*********";

                $headers = array ('From' => $from,
                  'To' => $to,
                  'Cc' => $cc,
                  'Subject' => $subject,
                  'Content-type' => 'text/html');
                $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
                  array ('host' => $host,
                 'auth' => true,
                 'username' => $username,
                 'password' => $password));

                 $rec = $to.', '.$cc;

                $mail = $smtp->send($rec, $headers, $body);
```

Comment: change your if statement to use $email rather than $email_to

Comment: where does this go in my function?

Comment: @user2710234: You can use `imlplode()` on the result array to get the string. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19426001/1438393).

Comment: @user2710234 added an all together example

Comment: don't who who is the one who think this is not helpful even though rest of answers are same, the only different is that my answer was probably first.

Comment: how about validating the cc addresses too?

Comment: @user2710234 you can repeat same steps or wrap the validation section in a function and reuse it

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
foreach(explode(',', $sEmailAddresses) AS $sEmailAddress){
   $bValid |= filter_var($sEmailAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
}

$sResult = ($bValid) ? 'Both are valid' : 'One of them are not';
```